# cheerio nodejs помогите разобраться

Tags: node.js, cheerio

вот есть кусок html кода сайта

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-panel-padding">
<div class="panel panel-info panel-full-height">
<div class="panel-heading">Active Buy Orders</div>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="50%">Price</th>
<th width="50%">Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>$3.11</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$3.10</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$2.94</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$1.50</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

как мне вытащить первое значение в столбце price $3.11 ? 
пробовал так

```
var P = $('div .table-responsive').text()
```

получается много лишнего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Много лишнего потому что брать нужно ячейку, а не всю таблицу. Попробуйте так:

```
var P = $('.table-responsive td').eq(0).text();
```

или вот так:

```
var P = $('.table-responsive td').first().text();
```

Comment: throw new SyntaxError("unmatched pseudo-class :" + name);
   ^

SyntaxError: unmatched pseudo-class :eq
все равно такая ошибка)

Comment: вроде как cheerio  в заголовке написал же)

Comment: спасибо второй вариант заработал )

Comment: Теперь и первый должен работать, исправил